# custom field as a button in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, field

I would like to create a sharPoint custom column which contains a button that redirect user to the display form of the item.
i would like to see my button in list view for each item so that the user can display the item when clicking the button.

How to reach my requirement ?

Thanks

Comment: Clicking the "Title" column value already has this effect; if you really need your own graphical button, consider using a simple SharePoint Designer Workflow to generate the HTML for one automatically whenever an item is added to the list - all you need to do is link to the DispForm.aspx page passing the ID of the list item.

Comment: I know that the title column has the same effect but my client need a graphical button. How to reach my requirement using SharePoint Designer ? what are the workflow steps ?

Comment: Create a new workflow that automatically runs on an item being added, don't set any conditions, use the Action to build a string that is the HTML for the button you want, somewhere in that HTML create a hyperlink to the DispForm.aspx page that appends the ID of the item, and write that HTML into a field in the item.

Comment: helpful reply stev..thanks